# Exporting Report Data for Release Pipelines

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We have Power BI reporting for our Pipelines and I am able to get details such as Tasks/Runs/Jobs etc.. for all "BUILD" pipelines. But I am not able to do this for "RELEASE" pipelines. I can get the "Release Pipeline Overview" in ADO but I am not able to connect and export this data to Power BI for in-depth analysis.

Release Pipeline Overview :

[image]